# Accessing to target values in vba simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code what it basically do is: i want to access two triggers or target values and based on their respective values, it perform on action. Ex:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Target.Column = 19 And Target.row = 17 Then
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
'do something
End if 
End Sub
If Target.Column = 20 And Target.row = 18 Then
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
'do something
End if 
End Sub
```

What this does is, it only checks one trigger value at a time. When trigger1.value changes, it doesn't check trigger2.value
However what i really wanted to do is:

```
if triger1.value = "Yes" and triger2.value = "yes" then 
'' do something
elseif triger1.value = "No" and triger2.value = "yes"
'' do another thing
end if
and so on
```

my question now is: how can i access the two triggers simultaneously and if the value one trigger is updated, it will check the second trigger value and decide what to do. Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    
    Dim trigger1 As Range, trigger2 As Range
    Set trigger1 = Me.Range("S17")
    Set trigger2 = Me.Range("T18")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(trigger1, trigger2)) Is Nothing Then
        If trigger1.Value = "Yes" And trigger2.Value = "Yes" Then
            'do something
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Any time either of the triggers is changed, this will check to see if both triggers are set to "Yes". If they are then the code will run (if you change the "do something" to the necessary functions)

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the first `end sub` in your macro: it makes your macro stop at that moment and the other lines are not even read anymore.

Comment: I think OP has `End Sub` there because they have tried to merge two subs to get the desired functionality. Unfortunately they left the `End Sub`, so it was destined to not even compile. However, even if they remove the `End Sub`, the code still won't work as they want it to (both triggers being checked together).

Answer (score 1):

For complicated checks, you *can* use a Boolean to store the True/False value, and check that later.

```
Dim bContinue AS Boolean
bContinue = False

If Target.Column = 19 And Target.row = 17 Then bContinue = True
If Target.Column = 20 And Target.row = 18 Then bContinue = True

If bContinue = True Then
    'If Trigger1...
End If
```

However, your current code is simple enough that an `OR` should work:

```
If (Target.Column = 19 And Target.row = 17) OR (Target.Column = 20 And Target.row = 18) Then
```

After that, Row 18, Column 20 of the sheet will be `Me.Cells(18, 20)`.  Similarly, Row 17, Column 19 will be `Me.Cells(17, 19)`

This allows you to do this:

```
If Me.Cells(17, 19).Value = "Yes" And Me.Cells(18,20).Value = "Yes" Then
    'Do Something
'' do something
elseif Me.Cells(17, 19).value = "No" and Me.Cells(18,20).value = "yes"
'' do another thing
end if
```

However, if the only possible values are "Yes" and "No" (i.e. no "Maybe" or blank) then you can combine things into a Switch Statement with a bit of Binary:

```
Select Case (IIF(Me.Cells(17, 19).Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIF(Me.Cells(18, 20).Value = "Yes", 2, 0))
    Case 0: '0b00
        'Both are "No"
    Case 1: '0b01
        '"Yes" and "No"
    Case 2: '0b10
        '"No" and "Yes"
    Case 3: '0b11
        'Both are "Yes"
    Case Else:
        'Something has gone wrong
End Select
```

(The `Worksheet_Change` function is attached to the Worksheet, so you can use the special keyword `Me` to refer to the Worksheet.  If this was code in a Module, then that would not work)

Comment: +1 -- really nice explanation. I think making variables of the two triggers is helpful, though, so that you don't have to keep making reference to the row and column numbers (and potentially making awkward mistakes!). Just my preference though!

Comment: That was also my preference but one triggers works at a time. if tigers one is triggered and the value of trigger two is not updated or it doent read it.

Answer (score -1):

### A Worksheet Change (Multiple Cells)

**Standard Module, e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TriggerS17T18( _
        ByVal Target As Range)
' Needs the 'ConcatRange' function.
    Const ProcName As String = "TriggerS17T18"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const rgAddress As String = "S17,T18"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = sws.Range(rgAddress)
    If Intersect(Target, rg) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' The following line is crucial if you're going to process the same
    ' worksheet, because it will prevent retriggering the event while it
    ' is still running.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim cString As String: cString = UCase(ConcatRange(rg))
    
    ' Possibly Needed References
    ' Create a reference to the workbook.
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = sws.Parent ' Set wb = Target.Worksheet.Parent
    ' Create a reference to worksheet "Sheet2".
    'Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    ' When done testing, replace the `MsgBox cString` lines with your code.
    Select Case cString
    Case "YESYES"
        MsgBox cString
    
    Case "YESNO"
        MsgBox cString
    
    Case "NOYES"
        MsgBox cString
    
    Case "NONO"
        MsgBox cString
    
    Case Else
        MsgBox cString
    
    End Select
    
SafeExit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Not Application.ScreenUpdating Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub

Function ConcatRange( _
    ByVal mrg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String) _
As String
    Const ProcName As String = "ConcatRange"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim mCell As Range
    For Each mCell In mrg.Cells
        ConcatRange = ConcatRange & CStr(mCell.Value) & Delimiter
    Next
    ConcatRange = Left(ConcatRange, Len(ConcatRange) - Len(Delimiter))

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Sheet Module, e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    TriggerS17T18 Target
End Sub
```